# Markers not plotting on map using Mapbox and leaflet?

Tags: jquery, leaflet, mapbox

I am trying to plot markers from the data I receive for the server. The data is coming in and I can dump via console.log and similarly the marker is also being created as I can dump it also via console.log but the only problem is that I cannot see the marker plot on the map.

The code is as follows:

```
var pivotsLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer();

function plotPivots(farm_id){
                $.getJSON('farm/' + farm_id + '/pivots', function(data){
                    $.each(data, function(pivot_i, pivot_item){
                        if(pivot_item.lat != ''){
                            console.log(pivot_item);
                            var marker = L.marker([parseFloat(pivot_item.lat), parseFloat(pivot_item.long)]).addTo(pivotsLayer);
                            console.log(marker);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
```

What could I possibly be doing wrong if I can see all the information in console log?

The whole code:

```
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoicm9oYW4wNzkzIiwiYSI6IjhFeGVzVzgifQ.MQBzoHJmjH19bXDW0b8nKQ';
        var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'inclanfunk.l4mg4b99', {
            zoomControl: false
        }).setView([-39.67, -69.26], 4);

        // Disable drag and zoom handlers.
        map.dragging.disable();
        map.touchZoom.disable();
        map.doubleClickZoom.disable();
        map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();

        // Disable tap handler, if present.
        if (map.tap) map.tap.disable();

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('header h2').text('Equipment Map');

            plotDistributorCompanies();

            map.on('click', function(e){
                map.setView([-39.67, -69.26], 4);
                removeFarmsLayers();
                map.addLayer(distributorCompaniesLayer);
                map.addLayer(farmsLayer);
                plotDistributorCompanies();
            });

            var distributorCompanies = false;
            var distributorCompaniesLayer = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
            var farmsLayer = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);

            var pivotsLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);

            function removeDistributorCompaniesLayers(){
                distributorCompaniesLayer.clearLayers();
                map.removeLayer(distributorCompaniesLayer);
            }

            function removeFarmsLayers(){
                farmsLayer.clearLayers();
                map.removeLayer(farmsLayer);
            }

            function plotDistributorCompanies(){
                if(!distributorCompanies){
                    $.getJSON('distributor-companies', function (data) {
                        distributorCompanies = true;
                        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                            if (item.geojson != '') {
                                var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(distributorCompaniesLayer);
                                $.getJSON('/geojson/' + item.geojson, function (data) {
                                    featureLayer.setGeoJSON(data);
                                    featureLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
                                        layer.on('click', function (e) {
                                            map.fitBounds(featureLayer.getBounds());
                                            removeDistributorCompaniesLayers();
                                            plotFarms(item.id);
                                            distributorCompanies = false;
                                        });
                                    });
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            }

            function plotFarms(distributor_id){
                $.getJSON('distributor/' + distributor_id + '/farms', function(data){
                    $.each(data, function(farm_i, farm_item){
                        if(farm_item.geojson != ''){
                            var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(farmsLayer);
                            $.getJSON('/geojson/' + farm_item.geojson, function(data){
                                featureLayer.setGeoJSON(data);
                                featureLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
                                    layer.on('click', function (e) {
                                        map.fitBounds(featureLayer.getBounds());
                                        removeFarmsLayers();
                                        plotPivots(farm_item.id);
                                    });
                                });
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
            }

            function plotPivots(farm_id){
                $.getJSON('farm/' + farm_id + '/pivots', function(data){
                    $.each(data, function(pivot_i, pivot_item){
                        if(pivot_item.lat != ''){
                            console.log(pivot_item);
                            var circle = L.circle([parseFloat(pivot_item.lat), parseFloat(pivot_item.long)], parseInt(pivot_item.radius)).addTo(pivotsLayer);
                            console.log(circle);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }


        });
```

The data returned for the pivots:

```
[
{
"id": "4",
"farm_id": "101",
"distributor_id": "2",
"lat": "-68.51074219",
"long": "-28.93124697",
"radius": "100.00",
"brand": "Valley",
"model": "8000",
"coa": "8 5\/8",
"coa_model": "Flexible",
"ndd": "0",
"ddd": "0",
"sprinkler_model": "IWOB",
"sprikler_type": "Flat",
"sprikler_counterweight": "Yes",
"regulator_brand": "Nelson",
"regulator_type": "10 PCI",
"regulator_range": "All Range",
"wheel_size": "14x9x24",
"co_length": "2",
"co_diameter": "3",
"co_drops": "0",
"alignment": "Standard",
"re_brand": "Baldor",
"re_type": "High",
"re_rpm": "34",
"re_relation": "52:1",
"masa_brand": "Valley",
"masa_type": "Fixed",
"masa_relation": "36 RPM",
"spreader_type": "Fixed",
"rotation_time": "",
"sheet": "",
"minimum_working_pressure": "",
"input_voltage": "",
"shut_down_low_voltage": "",
"minimum_voltage": "",
"working_pressure": "",
"shut_down_for_low_pressure": "",
"last_wheel_cycle": "",
"pressuring_time": "",
"pressurization_recon_time": "",
"electical_conn_time": "",
"restart_time": "",
"electrical_board_model": "Basic",
"electrical_board_contactors": "",
"electrical_board_brand": "Weg",
"relay_board": "",
"protections": "",
"main_fuses": "10 amp",
"main_fuses_comment": "",
"panel_fuses": "10 amp",
"panel_fuses_comment": "",
"panel_code": "",
"lightning_arrester_code": "",
"voltage_source_code": "",
"pressure_sensor_code": "",
"created_at": "2015-02-22 11:01:17",
"updated_at": "2015-02-22 11:01:17"
}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not adding your `L.mapbox.featureLayer` (pivotslayer) to you mapinstance:

```
var pivotsLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer();
```

Assuming you have a reference to your map instance in a variable called `map`:

```
var pivotsLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);
// or
map.addLayer(pivotsLayer);
```

I've tried your data: http://plnkr.co/edit/VjijEh?p=preview and your circle is ending up somewhere in the atlantic above antarctica. Seems the lat/lng has been swapped ;) Problem solved.

Comment: I tried. Still doesn't work. In fact I tried plotting the markers straight to the map itself. Still won't work. And I also tried plotting a marker outside the loop to test just to have a look. Do you want me to post the whole code?

Comment: If you could, including some test data, would be nice. Creating a Plunker which demonstrates your problem is even beter, here's a boilerplate: http://plnkr.co/edit/VjijEh?p=info

Comment: Like the object that returns from the server. If you want I can copy and post it in the question?

Comment: Yup. The data that get's returned from $.getJSON and the rest of the code including your map etc.

Comment: I am trying to plot a circle now instead of a marker. Just letting you know.

Comment: The data returned from the server has only one pivot right now, but the code should work for any number, other than the fact that it doesn't right now because the circle is not being plotted.

Comment: That's too comprehensive to make a normal testcase of. Do you get any errors in your console? Do the companies and farms get plotted? This must be a very simple problem which is easy to debug if you just strip down your code to the bare minimum.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71442/discussion-between-rohan-and-ih8).